# JS Switch Checkbox Button clickes two times in one click

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a switch button(0/1 Button). I click one time but return both 0 and 1 together. I need return 0 **OR** 1

[image]
[image]

```
 <label class="switch s-outline s-outline-success">
        <input type="checkbox" name="product-images-check" class="checkbox_check">
        <span class="slider round"></span>
 </label>
```

Jquery - JS

```
$("label").on("click", function() {
             if($(this).children("input").is(":checked")) {
             console.log("Checkbox is checked.");
             }
             else if($(this).children("input").is(":not(:checked)")) {
             console.log("Checkbox is unchecked.");
             }
             console.log("CLICKED");
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attach the event listener to the checkbox instead of the label.

```js
$("label > input[type=checkbox]").on("click", function() {
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
        console.log("Checkbox is checked.");
    } else {
        console.log("Checkbox is unchecked.");
    }
    console.log("CLICKED");
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <label class="switch s-outline s-outline-success">
        <input type="checkbox" name="product-images-check" class="checkbox_check">
        <span class="slider round">Click me</span>
 </label>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply remove the condition inside else if and make it else block.

```js
$("label").on("click", function() {
             if($(this).children("input").is(":checked")) {
             console.log("Checkbox is checked.");
             }
             else {
             console.log("Checkbox is unchecked.");
             }
             console.log("CLICKED");
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="switch s-outline s-outline-success">
        <input type="checkbox" name="product-images-check" class="checkbox_check">
        <span class="slider round"></span>
 </label>
```